# Testing CoreMotion APIs (which require M7) on iphone simulator with iOS 7

Tags: ios7, core-motion, apple-m7

Has anyone successfully tested any of the new CoreMotion APIs with the simulator? It seems that those which require M7 aren't working. I've tried calling these functions on the new simulator running iOS 7

```
(BOOL)isActivityAvailable
```

and

```
(BOOL)isStepCountingAvailable
```

but both function calls return false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computer doesn't have an M7 so why would a simulator tell you it's there?

Edit: (Until the device Simulator supports faking it.)

Comment: Isnt it similar to how the GPS simulator works on Xcode? You don't have an actual GPS sensor embedded in your computer, but it still gets simulated data.

Comment: Nevermind you are right... I suppose location data is processed differently, probably without GPS sensor.

Comment: @jimmyC it could very well be that some test data source is coming in later version of XCode too

Comment: Oh wow, how are we supposed to code for the M7 if we can't simulate it? I can't be running out everytime I have to test something.